# TableCell init with coder and init with style

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm trying to save custom cell objects and later on show them. But fail to understand the mechanism totally i have:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if((self = [super init])) {
        self.action = [decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"action"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

and

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {

    }
    return self;
}
```

this way I get my variable decoded but the tablecell doesn't show up at all. if I remove init with coder i do get my tablecell interface showed, but can't get variable decoded. What should I do to make this work?

Comment: usually, you wouldnt want to save tableViewCells. you would want to save the content of the cells, and later recreate the cells and fill them with content. If your way of storing the cells is intentional, please explain why you want to do this. it will help us find an answer.

Comment: Well the cells are highly customized depending on the data they need to show. So I though it would be better to create and save simply cell with custom variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i can see your problem.
still, you shouldnt save the cells themselves. just create a UITableViewCell-Subclass that accepts one object from which it will gather all of its content. if you need more than one class for this, thats fine too. You can easily create several subclasses for several usecases.
then just save the data-objects and recreate the cells when you need them again.
the reason for this is that your way creates massive overhead, because you are trying to save all the UIviews, Lables, etc that make up your cell. Also, UITableVIews are highly optimized and try to reuse existing cells which does not play well with your approach.

TL;DR:
You need dataobjects, which you can save in keyedArchivers, and you need tableviewcells that accept these objects and display the necessary data. Seriously, you will save yourself some trouble. Let me know if you need help and have fun

Comment: I guess your answer does make sense. I'll have to rethink my logic, thank you